# width: fit-content; working on Chrome but not explorer

Tags: html, css

I built an app and everything is displayed perfectly in Chrome, but if I open the app in Windows Explorer the containers are smaller than they should be.

I'm using `width: fit-content`. Is this something that only works with Chrome.

How can I make it so that it works with all browsers?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`width: fit-content` is still in experimental stages, and is currently supported on Chrome 46.x and above (without vendor prefix), FF 3.x and above (with vendor prefix). Not supported on either IE or edge. 
You can refer to compatibility chart here: [Browser compatibility for width:fit-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Browser_compatibility)

One alternative is to use `display: table`, which has the same effect as `width: fit-content`. Of course, there are other ways that you can try depending on what your requirements are.

```css
#fit-content {
  width: fit-content;
  background: pink;
}

#table {
  display: table;
  background: lightblue;
}

#normal {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="fit-content">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Wikipedesketch1.png"> fit-content
</div>
<div id="table">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Wikipedesketch1.png"> table
</div>
<div id="normal">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Wikipedesketch1.png"> normal
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to solve it for `height = "fit-content"`? apparently `display: "table"` doesn't do it

Comment: [CC: @LeoMessi]    Fitting to the height is the default behavior ov elements.

Answer (score 11):

It can be done with `width:auto` but only when an element is `display: inline-block` as well as setting the value as `right:inherit` or `left:inherit`.

Example:

```
.my_div {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    right:inherit; /* align to left */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have similar problem. In one div, have others with `display:inline-block`

For parent div use `white-space : nowrap;`

Don't forget to set to child's div `white-space : normal;`

```
.parent {
    width: max-content;
    white-space : nowrap;
}
.parent .child {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space : normal;
}
```

HTML example

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

another alternative is to use `width:auto;`
This works sometimes but it depends on your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, fixed it this way. Instead of using `width: fit-content;` you can use the snippet below.

[`inline-flex`](https://caniuse.com/?search=inline-flex) is well supported (even on IE11).

In the example below, `flex: none;` is only useful if the parent is set as a `display: flex;`.

```css
.element {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: none;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ops! my answer came in 4yrs later.

I was building mobile page and had the issue with `width: fit-content;`. the code below worked for me:

```
header nav ul {
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-table` worked for me

Comment: It's hard to say what exactly doesn't work for that user since there no additional code provided, so the answer also seems not to help much.