# <H2> Underlined title auto-width on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, width, underline

```css
#skills
{
    width: intrinsic;
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <h2 id="skills">skills</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

I'm working on a website where I would like to underlined h2 titles in a better way than underlined css property.
Founding a trick that consisted in adding a border bottom, I've now problems in auto-fitting content.

My code was organized like this :

HTML part (with my 'box' div which is a flexbox) :

The underline style is perfect but it's not fitted on IE...

[image: h2 underlined]

I found some questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095440/width-fit-content-working-on-chrome-but-not-explorer/49095568) and tried to modify like :

```
#skills
{
    display: table;
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Could you help me ?

Thank you for your help,

Jerry

Comment: IE doesn't support `fit-content`. Can you try adding `display: inline-block` to `#skills` ? It should work for all browsers and you won't need the rest of the browser-specific properties

Comment: is there a reason not to use text-decoration ? What result do you expect ? *(display:table works for every browsers including IE8 and is a good alternative to width:max-content)*.  --which version of ie is an issue ? Your piece of code doesn't show underlined text or bottom borders .. can you clarify to help yourself ?

Comment: @volt : I already tried this solution but it doesn't works :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @user1833903 it works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cq3kbgrn/)

Comment: @G-Cyr : I didn't use text-decoration because it underlined but too close to the text. I underlined using border-bottom property in .box h2 css style zone. It's one of the newest version of IE.

Comment: @volt : it works but the h2 has still the same dimension as his parent and not fit the content (text..) size

Comment: It does actually fit the width of the content. I guess I don't understand what you want. Are you trying to show everything on the same line? Like both the heading and the paragraph that comes after it?

Comment: Ok no I resolved ; Think as box was a flexbox, #skills automatically takes the full width of the box. I insert an intermediate div around h2 and goes on with display: table ! Thank you for your help

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your help, I resolved my question.
The correct solution was to add an intermediate div like this :

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="intermediate"><h2 id="skills">skills</h2></div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

And then define as display: table; skills element.

As box element was a flexbox, skills had the same dimension of his parent. Adding an intermediate div, the intermediate div takes all space but next skills has a proper width.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I used border bottom and float left css
Hopefully this help :)

```css
    #skills {
    float: left;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
     /* This creates the border. Replace black with whatever color you want. */
    padding: 5px;
     }

    p {
      clear: both;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="box">
          <h2 id="skills">skills</h2><br>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          <h3 id="skills">skills skills</h3>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
          <h1 id="skills">skills skills skills</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: What I am looking to do is finding a way to have a dynamic size --> a sort of width: fit-content but for IE.. :)

Comment: I edit my answer please check and let me know if it works now :)

Comment: Not works because my #skills element is in a flexbox so takes 100% of his parent size :( But I create an intermediate div and seems working !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `float` would do what you want.

```css
.skills {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

p {
  clear: both;
}

.box {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2 class="skills">skills</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <h2 class="skills">Superior skills</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```